# Android shared element transition only working when leaving an activity not when entering

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I am using a shared element transition to animate an image view from an activity A to an activity B. 
I am using the following code for this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(v2, "logo");
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                     makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) mContext,p1);
context.startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

My theme is :

```
<style name="AnimationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>

    </style>
```

with "logo" being the transitionName for the image view in both A and B. 
But I notice that while the image transitions from B->A as expected, the transition from A->B doesn't work and there is simply a fade animation between the two activities.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this to make the image animate from A->B as well ?

NOTE : A is an activity with a recycler view of images, each of which opens into a detail activity(B) with the image transitioning between the two activities.

Thanks!

Comment: same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846447/android-sharedelementtransition-imageview-not-moving-properly

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the image using any imageloading library then you need to setup listener on image download.

```
private final RequestListener<Integer, GlideDrawable> listener = new RequestListener<Integer, GlideDrawable>() {
       @Override
       public boolean onException(Exception e, Integer model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Integer model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
           startPostponedEnterTransition();
           return false;
       }
};


Glide.with(getActivity()).load(list.get(position).getId()).listener(listener).into(imageView);
```

Call `PostponeEnterTransition()` in `OnCreate` of Detail Activity and call `startPostponeRequest` in `OnResourceReady`.

```
private void startPostponedEnterTransition() {
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested all answers like deleting animations or `startPostponedEnterTransition()` and so. nothing worked.finally this line solved my problem . Add this in your style.xml. This prevents the screen from Blinking

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```